# Accessing ungrouped data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Date      Cost
Jan       0   
Feb       0   
Jan       400  
Jan       50  
Mar       150  
Feb       0 
Apr       1000   
Apr       5
```

I have grouped the above dataframe using `get_groupby(0)` option on the dataframe, so that I can get all the 0 values grouped.

As shown in below code, I have created a dataframe `unpaid` with 0 in it.

```
unpaid = cost.get_group(0)
```

So is there any inverse of that option where I can get the rest of the data except 0's.

Note: My actual data is very huge which can't be put up here, and contains multiple values other than 0 like shown in the sample data.

Comment: What is the question? And what is `get_groupby`?

Comment: Can you add additional code with a simple example to your question?

Comment: I want to get only the data where there are no '0' in the column. The above shown dataframe is just an example and it has been derived from modifying main huge dataframe. @yatu

Comment: I have edited the post, please have a look. @conmak

Answer (score 0):

Taking your title for granted, i.e.

> Accessing ungrouped data in a dataframe

Something you can do is:

```
>>> ungrouped_data = cost._selected_obj
   Cost Date
0     0  Jan
1     0  Feb
2   400  Jan
3    50  Jan
4   150  Mar
5     0  Feb
6  1000  Apr
7     5  Apr
```

From there, to perform the [negative search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_search) you want,

```
>>> ungrouped_data[ungrouped_data.Cost > 0]
   Cost Date
2   400  Jan
3    50  Jan
4   150  Mar
6  1000  Apr
7     5  Apr
```

There is indeed no negative search functionality implemented via [~.get_group](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.1/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L822-L847).